# Rails 6 frontend architecture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile, architecture, frontend, ruby-on-rails-6

I am developing a new app from scratch in rails 6 and I'm looking for a simple way to:

1. Allow users to access the app offline and
2. Access some native features of the phone: like Geolocation, Camera and Bluetooth.

Indeed, I'm looking to keep the architecture as simple as possible in the frontend and avoid having two code-bases.

The app itself is not very complex (think of a "listing app" similar to AirBnb) but given the targeted users, I would like to have strong control over the design.

I should underline that I am a hobbyist developer (in my last project I used rails 3 --yep, that's a long time ago! ; ) so I would prefer to avoid learning "yet another framework". For that reason, I would like to use html 5 / css as much as possible, in order to keep the development experience as close as possible to a simple web-app.

Question: what frontend framework and / or approach would better answer to my needs?

Answer (score 1):

I see the two forms below:

1- You can create a pwa (Progressive Web App) with rails so you can use offline resources.

2- You can create an api with rails and develop an outside project with react and if you want a mobile app you can use react native.

For the first option, there is a rails gem called ServiceWorker::Rails.

For the second option you can use the rails new app --api command, to create a cleaner project prepared for building an api